# How can this statement manage to bypass MySQL replication

Tags: mysql, database-replication

Using MySQL 5.1.71

I have setup MASTER MASTER replication on **MY_REPLICATED_DB** which works.

I have 2 databases : **MY_REPLICATED_DB** and **MY_NORMAL_DB** (not the real names !)

However it can be bypassed if I log into mysql command line using the non replicated database name like so:

```
mysql --user=user_name --password=your_password MY_NORMAL_DB
```

and issue the following INSERT statement:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO MY_REPLICATED_DB.MY_TABLE values ('aaaaaaaaa');
```

If I connect using the following (i.e. no database specified)

```
mysql --user=user_name --password=your_password
```

and issue the following INSERT statement to the same table:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO MY_REPLICATED_DB.MY_TABLE values ('bbbbbbbbb');
```

it replicates fine.

This is wrong surely ?

Comment: See this : http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74393/strange-issue-with-mysql-5-6-replication  and final comment here : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-rules.html

Comment: This doesn't apply - it will replicate it's just that I have found a way to bypass it !